# Retrieving data from FireBase Database containing multiple subnodes using a specific orderby

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have been trying to retrieve the Data "in red" without knowing "the blue" key's value ( assuming there is multiple child with random keys) ,but i couldn't come up with the appropriate code .
This is the Firebase Children tree.

[image: db image]

I tried to write this code but it doesn't work (i am a beginner)

```
 List<String> idlist = new ArrayList<String>();
 DatabaseStage = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Stages");
 Query query = DatabaseStage.orderByChild("uniqueId").equalTo(stageid);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> stagedata = dataSnapshot.child("userEtudList").getChildren();
            for(DataSnapshot it: stagedata){
                if (!(it.getValue().equals("test"))){
                    idlist.add(it.getValue().toString());
                }
            }
```

Ps : if you are wondering about the use of orderByChild(uniqueId).equalTo(stageid) in this case stageid is equal to 2fdedf71-4346-4395-bee5-38db04d4fd47 it allows me to select one specific child which is the second one .

Here is the state of the variables obtained using breakpoints as you can see the Datasnapshot it keeps getting {key = userEtudList , Value =null} but not getting to Children

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer I'm interpreting your question as "I want to generate a list of all values, without regard for their key, in the `userEtudList` node of the selected `Stages` node.  (e.g. tell me which students are in that course).  Likewise, that your code that deals with the `test` values is really just test code and isn't really relevant to this challenge.

---

Your problem is that `dataSnapshot` isn't really a single node.  Its a set of all matching nodes at the level of the database where you made the query.  The fact that there is only one item in this case because of your `equalTo` doesn't really matter.  (e.g. imagine how this code works without your `equalTo` call in the query -- it can't, since it doesn't know which item in the snapshot to get the `userEtudList` child from!).  This is why when you try to get the `userEtudList` child the snapshot is empty.  [Doc Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events)

> Calling getValue() on a snapshot returns the Java object representation of the data. If no data exists at the location, calling getValue() returns null.

**To fix this**, you should probably assert that `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 1` and then:

```java
Iterable<DataSnapshot> stagedata = dataSnapshot.getChildren()
    .iterator().next()
    .child("userEtudList").getChildren();
```

---

If you were able to somehow rely on the key name always being equal to `uniqueId` (its not clear to me why you are storing `uniqueId` as something other than the key anyway // possibly, this is just an artifact of using a screenshot of the database) you could avoid this by:

```java
Iterable<DataSnapshot> stagedata = dataSnapshot.child(stageid)
    .child("userEtudList").getChildren();
```

Of course, in this case, the entire query can be removed and you can just retrieve this node directly in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

So i figured it out this is what worked for me

```
DatabaseStage = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Stages").child(stageid).child("userEtudList");
DatabaseStage.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mData.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                mData.add(data);
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the simplest approach since the object key is indeed the same as `uniqueId`.  This is why its best practice to include the JSON of your database, rather than screenshots - your screenshot shows only the truncated value of `uniqueId`.  Glad its working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Database queries can have at most one unknown key. So unless you know either the `2fded...fd47` key of the `0` key, there's no way to look up the specific node you've marked in red.

Comment: I found a way to remove the orderBy so no need to use query , can't i directly retrieve the "userEtudList" in hashmap or in a list?